# Place data sequentially on view from different tables

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an online voting system in which 3 `candidates` will participate. I have a relation between two tables `candidate` and `voter`. I am sending all data of all rows to the view and want to show pictures in different tags. The major problem is that here is no sequence so I can't use loop in this situation.

This is my view:

```
//some code 

<img src='example.jpg'>

//some code and then again img tag

<img src='example.jpg'>
```

Comment: share the structure of the data that you are sending to the view

Comment: it is just a simple candidate::all() query in which candidate pictures and name are retrieve from database simple. and i want to show them here

Comment: i simply want to show the pictures in different tags that are not in sequence so in this case i cant use loop because it have to place on different places.please help me

Comment: please add more detail, like your model structure and relations, how you send the data to the blade and the format of the data that ends up in the blade

Answer (score 0):

Best way that I use frequently if two tables can have same methods or have same logical code is to create a Trait

```
<?php
 namespace App\Traits;

 trait HasPicture
 {
     public function picture()
     {
         //return path of picture or anythings else
     }
 }
```

And both in `Candidate` and `Vote` you will use the trait

```
<?php
 use App\Traits\HasPicture;
```

Finnaly, in your view, you can easly call `$vote->picture` or `$candidate->picture`